# How to add "or" in css path for jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any way I can use `"or"` in `css selector` like we use in Xpaths? I need to extract titles from certain pages. In some pages title will be in `h3` tag and in some pages it will be `h4`.

I tried the following code, it didnt return anything.

```
$('h3[class="toUpper"] or h4[class="bold"]').text().trim()
```

Comment: Just replace `or` with a comma (`,`). Exactly how you would in CSS.

Comment: `$('h3.toUpper, h4.bold')`

Comment: It worked, Thank you. And I didnt find the other question when I searched for `or` function in `css selector`, I didnt know it was a duplicate question.